# Scatterplot matrix using two dataframes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatterplot Matrix between a group of variables (not all!) in my dataframe.

A quick snapshot of my dataFrame:

```
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    R1    R2
.08  .05   .93   .1    .21   .32    .21   .09  .07
.43  .12   .1   .40    .07   .98    .25   .10  .05
```

The two groups are **V1 to V7** and **R1-R2**. So what I'm trying to achieve is a plot between *V1-R1*, *V1-R2*, *V2-R1*.......*V7-R2*. I do not want to plot *V1-V2*, *V1-V4* etc.

I figured an easy way to get to this would be to split my dataframe into two which would enable me to achieve my goal.

So I split my dataframe into two as below:

`dataFrame1<-dataframe[,1:7]`

`dataFrame2<-dataframe[,8:9]`

This works well as far as getting the correlation table out from R is concerned:

`cor(dataFrame1,dataFrame2)`

however the plotting bit is a bit of a challenge.

I have thus far tried **ggpairs**, **car** and **scatterplotMatrix** and none of them seem to work.

For ggpairs using the current code as below:

```
ggpairs (dataFrame1, dataFrame2)
```

I get the following error message

> Make sure your 'columns' values are positive.

Of course the above dataFrame is just a sample of the entire dataset and hence you cannot see any negatives in R1 and R2.

I don't want to manually do it in ggplot2 and then use glob to merge into a single plot. Also I don't want to plot the matrix for all the variables as is because that is not what I am trying to achieve.

Is there another way to get to what I'm after?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution. First subset you original df into two different data.frames; turn them into a long form, needed for ggplot; then merge the data.frames by rows (I added an id variable for that) and plot the result with `facet_grid`.

```
# Simulating data
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  V1 = rnorm(100),
  V2 = rnorm(100),
  V3 = rnorm(100),
  R1 = rnorm(100),
  R2 = rnorm(100),
  R3 = rnorm(100))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Subset the data.frames
df1 <- select(df,id,starts_with("V"))
df2 <- select(df,id,starts_with("R"))

# Turn them both to long form and merge them
dft <- gather(df1,var,value,-id) %>% 
  left_join(gather(df2,var,value,-id),by="id")

ggplot(data = dft,aes(x = value.x,y=value.y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(var.x~var.y)
```

[image]

On a side note, your code produces this error because `ggpairs` does not expect two data.frames. See `?GGally::ggpairs` :

> ggpairs(data, columns = 1:ncol(data) ...)

The second argument should be the columns index; you are passing a whole data.frame. `ggpairs` doesn't seem to be able to do what you want, but it would plot every variable against every other if you just passed it the whole original dataframe : `ggpairs(dataframe)`.